# React DatePicker toggle issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

i'm using this plugin in my project. 
https://reactdatepicker.com

There is have some prop `showTimeSelect` this prop takes boolean value and hide or show time picker.

I'm trying to give option to user about selecting time picker, so i tried to make some onClick event and make this prop conditional.

But it's work sometimes, sometimes not..

I don't understand where is the problem here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    startDate: new Date()
  };

  handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date,
      showTime: false
    });
  };

  showTimeSelection = () => {
    this.setState({
      showTime: !this.state.showTime
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          showTimeSelect={this.state.showTime}
        >
          {" "}
          <div>
            <a onClick={() => this.showTimeSelection()}>
              TOGGLE TIME SELECTION
            </a>
          </div>{" "}
        </DatePicker>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

and here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-monad-meswh?fontsize=14) example

You can try on codeSandBox it's sometimes work directly sometimes you need to click outside of datepicker and click inside again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed it only works if `showTimeSelect` is `true` before the `DatePicker` is going to be displayed. So, before closing `DatePicker` you have to set `showTimeSelect` to true. you can do it in prop `onClickOutside`

```
 state = {
    startDate: new Date(),
    showTime: true
  };

  handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  };

  showTimeSelection = () => {
    this.setState({
      showTime: !this.state.showTime
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { startDate, showTime } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          showTimeSelect={showTime}
          onClickOutside={() => this.setState({ showTime: true })}
        >
          <div onClick={this.showTimeSelection} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
            <h4>TOGGLE TIME SELECTION</h4>
          </div>
        </DatePicker>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

check out [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58725637-q557q) . check out [two](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-calendar-open-state-callbacks) other useful props `onCalendarClose` and `onCalendarOpen`

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much